# Mathematica on android phone

Tags: linux

I would like to practice mathematica programming on an android phone. Is there a site I can consult that gives feedback on how to go about it and running speed?

Comment: I had no idea Mathematica can be installed on smart phones as well. This is good to know, I always assumed it is only available for windows, mac and Linux on the PC only. You probably need lots of memory on your smart phone for this, might be a little slow also? I would suggest at least 8 GB Ram for it.

Comment: @Nasser Can it though? There's the Wolfram Cloud app, but it runs in the cloud, not on the phone.

Comment: @Szabolcs   I assumed it can, since the OP is asking about running Mathematica on smart phone. As I said in my comment, I did not know Mathematica could run on the smart phone. I have not really been up to the latest technology trends myself.

Comment: I did a little bit of research on this, and it looks like @Szabolcs is correct. Mathematica does not run on smart phone, but there is an app  [app/wolfram-cloud](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wolfram-cloud/id978701305) only. So It does not look like you can do Mathematica programming on the smart phone at this time. Sometime ago, I read that Mathematica will have a release on the IPAD. I do not know what happened with that as well. I do not keep up with these things.

Comment: There is an approach to install and run Mathematica on an android smart phone. The key is installing a Linux virtual machine on your smart phone and installing a free Mathematica running in Raspberry Pi. I installed one long time before and it's useless. If you can understand Chinese you can visit https://tieba.baidu.com/p/4839429399  for more details. The link of the files is https://pan.baidu.com/s/1kVoDjjp  and the access code is `skhq`

Comment: You can write new content with the [cloud version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wolfram.android.cloud). I far as I know, running content locally is currently only [available](https://blog.wolfram.com/2017/10/04/notebooks-in-your-pocket-wolfram-player-for-ios-is-now-shipping/) for iOS.

Comment: There is a Mathematica build for Raspberry Pi OS. That is mainly a Debian build on ARM platform. Can it be ported to run on a typical Android, which already comes with a Linux kernel on ARM?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [Mathematica build for Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/). In essence that is a version of Mathematica for Debian OS on ARM platform. I can verify that the following works:

1. Install Debian on Android using [UserLAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula), which by default thinks it runs on arm64 architecture (I'm using an arm64 android device).
2. Add armhf architecture by running "dpkg --add-architecture armhf"
3. install Mathematica. apt install mathematica.deb file seems to be missing something, but I can force open the deb archive, and extract all files.
4. Mathematica runs.

No virtual machine is used here, so Mathematica is running natively on Android.

Comment: I assume only the command line version runs, and perhaps many parts are broken? Can it export graphics?

Comment: You are right: only MathKernel runs. It can't export graphics, which requires Mathematica frontend. But all non-frontend feature of Mathematica I tried so far is working.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for posting this. I installed all necessary libs, but I got still

kirill@localhost:~$ wolfram
ERROR: ld.so: object '/support/libdisableselinux.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.3/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-ARM/WolframKernel: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to Wolfram Cloud, you can run the Wolfram Cloud app which is basically Mathematica.